# What's wrong with partial extension .erb instead of .html.erb to cover multiple formats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to use the same partial in .html.erb and .mobile.erb templates.

Are there any disadvantages to just naming the partial **_foo.erb**, instead of _foo.html.erb? It works the way I describe just fine.

Comment: Prefixing a partial with underscore makes sure that it's always used as a partial and never as a main template. I think that's the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. However, some people prefer to have the name include the actual format of the returned content. In that scenario, you'd also name your mobile template `.mobile.html.erb`.

It's also more en vogue to respond to both mobile and desktop requests with the same template, using responsive design. One (of many) reasons is that the mobile/desktop divide isn't really the dichotomy it used to be. There are now devises at any screen resolution from 200px width to >8000px width.